# What is the actual openCti resource to be used for a custom softphone implementation?

Tags: integration, service-cloud-console, opencti, cti, softphone

I am creating a custom softphone, and am using the below resources:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/support/api/38.0/lightning/opencti.js"></script>
<script src="/support/api/40.0/interaction.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, this is some issues as I'm unable to access any sforce.opencti functionality. Every basic operation is failing with the error:

**Cannot read property 'opencti' of undefined**

and I am unsure why.

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to work with a classic or Lightning console.

**Use Open CTI for Salesforce Classic if...**

- You want to make calls using a softphone in Salesforce Classic
- You want to make calls using a softphone in a Salesforce Classic
  console app

The URL would be `<https://domain:port>/support/api/49.0/interaction.js`

In this case, you will use below functions

```
//Set softphone height
sforce.interaction.cti.setSoftphoneHeight(300, callback);
```

Note this is relative. If you are building outside salesforce then you need to append the full salesforce domain.

**Use Open CTI for Lightning Experience if...**

- You want to make calls using a softphone in Lightning Experience
- You want to make calls using a softphone in a Lightning Experience
  console app

The URL would be `<https://domain:port>/support/api/49.0/lightning/opencti_min.js`

In this case, it would be

```
//Disable clickToDial
 sforce.opencti.disableClickToDial({callback: callback});
```

For lightning you can find a sample app [here](https://github.com/developerforce/open-cti-demo-adapter)

For Classic find sample code and dev guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_methods_intro_classic.htm)

Comment: Thank you Mohith! I was able to find out the right resources. ALso, I have a question on the methods available for Lightning vs Classic. For my implementation, I'm using Lightning out to use my aura component that is my actual dialler. But I see that there is no access to the console CTI API at all. Do you see any way to use sforce.console.cti in aura? I am very much looking to use onCallBegin() and onCallEnd() functions. If this is completely unusable, do you think there's any way to track when call begins and ends?

Comment: @ApexSrinivas Can you open a new question for this. Thanks

Comment: I added below question: 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310160/how-can-i-use-sforce-console-cti-methods-in-an-aura-component