# How can I use sforce.console.cti methods in an aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, api, service-cloud-console, opencti

I am looking to build a softphone on lightning. I see that there are several powerful methods of console API that are only available in Classic. But I need the same methods for Lightning in my aura component.

Is there any way to use sforce.console.cti methods in an aura component? Specifically, the onCallBegin and onCallEnd. If this is not possible, can you please suggest a way to listen to these events in my aura component?

Referred documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_fireoncallbegin.htm

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method parity between lightning console and the classic console is clearly documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_js_lightning_parity.htm)

As you can see in the bottom that the below methods are not supported

- onCallBegin()
- onCallEnd()
- onCallLogSaved()

I think this can be achieved with [Lightning Messaging Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_sample_lex_message_service.htm) now. You can release events on your page based on the API response you get in your server or based on user interaction events like when someone receives call using the dialer, ends it, or when someone clicks a button to save call Records.